# Calling protected method "Front" from ListQueue class, which implements Queue interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, comparator, method-call

I am having trouble figuring out how to make a call to the method "front", from my ListQueue class. The ListQueue class implements the interface "Queue", which also contains "front" as a variable. The method is public in Queue, and  protected in ListQueue.

When I try to call front with q1 and q2, the method is not recognized. I am assuming it is because of it's protected access modifier, since it recognizes other methods which have public access. If this is the case, is there a way around this without changing protected to public? I tried to add @Override above the method in ListQueue, but said that it won't override superclass.

```
public class BaseMerging {

private static Queue mergeQueues(Queue<Comparable> q1, Queue<Comparable> q2) {


    Queue<Comparable> ListQueue = new ListQueue<Comparable>();

    while (!q1.isEmpty() && !q2.isEmpty()) {
    **DOES NOT RECOGNIZE "FRONT" METHOD**
         if (!less(q1.*front()*, (q2.*front()*))) { 

            ListQueue.add(q1.poll());

        } else {

            ListQueue.add(q2.poll());
        }

    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
public class ListQueue<Item> implements Queue<Item> {

protected Item front() {
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    return head.getElement();
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
public interface Queue<Item> {


     public Item front() throws NoSuchElementException;

...

}
```

I thought that a class could access a protected method from another class as long as it was in the same package, but maybe I am wrong. Is it because ListQueue inherits "front" from Queue? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

When you are overriding super class method, access modifier cannot be more restrictive than super class method.

Your implementation violate that rule.

So you can't override public method with protected access modifier.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Check Modifiers section.